# Introscope 8.2.2 does not work with Java 7

Tags: java-7

I recently upgraded to Java 1.7 patch 40. After this when i try to access introscope I get following error:
"Failed to validate certificate. The application will not be executed". The stack trace is:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: algorithm constraints check failed
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.getValidationState(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.validateChain(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: algorithm constraints check failed
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
... 21 more
```

The introscope version i am using is 8.2.2. Is there a way to configure introscope to work with JRE 7?
What are the solutions I can consider? Why would not introscope work with JRE 7?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on CA forum, (but the page is no more available...):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html#AppB
--- excerpted from above link ---
Starting from JDK 7u40 release, the default value of jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms is as follows:
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
This means that no signature algorithm involving MD2 will be used to verify a certificate. And use of certificates with RSA key size of less than 1024 bits in length is restricted.
--- excerpted from above link ---

**The java.security file is located in your client machine's Java/JRE installed directory (jre/lib/security/java.security).**
In Java 1.7.0_40 the java.security by default has this setting:

`jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024`

**Changing the 1024 to 256 will solve the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

Run Java's ContolPanel and reduce your security settings.
Caveat -- this setting applies to all applets and Java Web Start (jnlp) applications.